# How to detect end of audio file when created dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

I've created an audio object using jQuery, like so

```
var player;

$(document).ready(function() {
    player = new Audio();
    player.id = "player";
    player.volume = 0.5;
});
```

I'm able to play, pause,... succesfully

```
player.src = file;
player.play();
```

This is when i run into trouble. I'm trying to detect when the player stops playing, but it's not working...

I've tried the following with no success:

```
$(document).on("ended", "#player", function(e) {
    alert('stop');
});

$("#player").bind("ended", function() {
    alert('stop');
});

$("#player").on("ended", function(e) {
    alert('stop');
});
```

How can i tell when the player has stopped using jQUERY?

Comment: Try using listener event. It might solve in your case.

Comment: I want to believe that `paused()` method is what you are looking for: [HTML Audio Object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_audio.asp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use `html5` audio element with pure `js`?

**[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_ended.asp)**

```
var aud = document.getElementById("myAudio");
aud.onended = function() {
    alert("The audio has ended");
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You are so close but should use `addEventListener` for `ended` `event`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    player = new Audio();
    player.volume = 0.5;
    var playerID = document.getElementById('player');
    
playerID.addEventListener("ended", function(e){
  alert('ended');
}, false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio controls id="player">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

<sub>*Audio credit by w3schools*</sub>